# Hadoop stand alone mode , dirName.className, gives classNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run hadoop in stand alone mode and have set up all the correct configuration files and have successfully run the wordCount example. The problem arises when I try to organize my source code and jar files into a file hierarchy to make things a little more organized.

```
hadoop --config ~/myconfig jar ~/MYPROGRAMSRC/WordCount.jar MYPROGRAMSRC.WordCount ~/wordCountInput/allData ~/wordCountOutput
```

I use the above code to invoke hadoop from a script file in my home directory. It fails to recognize the WordCount file one level below in the MYPROGRAMSRC directory.

The ~/MYPROGRAMSRC directory contains the:

`WordCount.jar, WordCount.java, WordCount.class, WordCount$Map.class and WordCont$Reduce.class` files.

Buy why is hadoop throwing a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MYPROGRAMSRC.WordCount
```

I know my program runs because if I transfer the script file into the same directory as the WordCount.class file and run the following command:

```
hadoop --config ~/myconfig jar WordCount.jar WordCount ~/wordCountInput/allData ~/wordCountOutput
```

It runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
hadoop --config ~/myconfig jar ~/MYPROGRAMSRC/WordCount.jar ~/MYPROGRAMSRC/WordCount ~/wordCountInput/allData ~/wordCountOutput
```

`MYPROGRAMSRC.WordCount` makes no sense if `MYPROGRAMSRC` is a directory.

Comment: That still doesn't work. I tried that too. It insists that the script file has to be in the same directory.

Comment: What is the script file?

Comment: well I just wrote a script file that does a bunch of other stuff along with running the command:                                                                               hadoop --config ~/myconfig jar WordCount.jar ~/MYPROGRAMSCR/WordCount ~/wordCountInput/allData ~/wordCountOutput                                  but that doesn't seem to work. Even if I try on the command line without the script file, it still works only if I am in the directory ~/MYPROGRAMSRC and just pass in WordCount as the class file . I was just curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: I am sorry, `MYPROGRAMSRC.WordCount`does make sense, if MYPROGRAMSRC is the package of WordCount.